# Chromecast Beta Google I/O 2014

Tags: chromecast, 5.0-lollipop

During Google I/O 2014, Google announced 'Android L' and a Chromecast update which will support 'Screen Mirroring'. This wasn't possible on earlier Android versions without rooting. The updates will be rolling out to users later this fall. However, they released an Android L Developer Preview for Nexus 5 and Nexus 7.

I own a Nexus 5 & Chromecast. I want to try this Screen Mirroring feature. I installed the Android L Developer Preview on my Nexus 5. Is there a beta release for Chromecast too? How can I start Screen Mirroring from my Nexus 5 (without rooting) to my Chromecast?

Comment: Screen mirroring to any Miracast device is already present in 4.4, so you don't need developer versions of anything. Find it in Settings → Display → Cast screen.

Comment: @DanHulme : I have been using Miracast for a while now. I wanted to mirror my phone's display using Chromecast, which I can, after the update starts rolling out for users. I wish to develop an app using this Chromecast feature. How can I start my development now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, Google released ChromeCast app v1.7, for selected devices running Android 4.4.1 and above. This enabled devices to use ScreenCast feature onto their ChromeCast.